# Inactive plugin error when using java applet on MacOSX10.6.8

Tags: java, macos, centos, osx-snow-leopard, webmin

I've set up webmin and it was working fine until yesterday.

I was trying to get it more secured. So I tried to put .htaccess with basic password authentication in the directory related to webmin.

However it didn't work at all. so I just enabled SSL for webmin.
This could be matter.

However now, File Manager in webmin won't work! It just shows "Inactive plugin"

How can I get it work again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the answer, as described on an [Apple discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4761112?tstart=0):

> sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete
>   :JavaWebComponentVersionMinimum" 
>       /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/XProtect.meta.plist

Comment: Thanks, but this is pretty risky to execute this on XProtect.  Do you think Apple will take care of this problem later on?

Answer (score 1):

Same error, same solution for me.

Thank-you Joel Bruner - I have been looking for this answer for half the day now!

---

Just adding that

- You must restart your browser for this to take effect - obvious but
  an easy mistake if you are frustrated.
- You do not need to restart your computer. Also double-check that
  Java is enable in your browser and in the preferences pane.

Please note as a helpful guide that the following does not work until you apply the above solution:

Updating Java

Deleting Cache

Changing Preference options

Re-installing Java from the apple website

Re-activating full preferences pane via terminal

Apple update

Restarting browsers or your computer

~mo~

Answer (score 0):

For others dealing with the Java "Inactive Plugin" issue on OS10.6: Apple has recently (March 4, 2013) released a Java update: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1573